# Limit of this sequence

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Hi I am learning for a calculus exam and I can't seem to find a way to find this sequence's limit

$$ a_n = \frac{3\ln(n^2+2n)}{\ln(\sqrt{n^4-1})+3\ln(5\ln(2n))} $$

I tried L'Hopitals rule, but then it gets really messy.

I would really appriciate it, if someone could give me hint.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok nvm I found the limit, it is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it as
$$
a_n=3\frac{2\ln n+\ln(1+\frac{2}{n})}{2\ln n+\ln\sqrt[4]{1-\frac{1}{n^4}}+3\ln(5\ln(2n))}=
3\frac{1+\dfrac{\ln(1+\frac{2}{n})}{2\ln n}}{1+\dfrac{\ln\sqrt[4]{1-\frac{1}{n^4}}}{2\ln n}+\dfrac{3\ln(5\ln(2n))}{2\ln n}}
$$

Comment: Thank you, this made it a lot easier. I'll mark it as the correct answer since I found the limit using this from.

Comment: @TheMaco The idea is guessing the dominant term, in this case $\ln(n^2)$.

Comment: Alright, thank you sir.